# How to access existing custom fields from SFDX-managed unlocked package?

Tags: metadata-api, custom-field, salesforcedx, package

Long ago, I added a field `Type__c` to `Contact` on our production org. Now, I'm using SFDX to develop an unlocked package with code that refers to that custom field, like `someContact.Type__c = 'Student'`.

With a newly-created scratch org, using `force:source:push` on this package gives the error

`Variable does not exist: Type__c`

because the custom field hasn't been defined in the scratch org. That makes sense, and I can fix it by retrieving the metadata for `Contact` from production and using `force:mdapi:deploy` to deploy that metadata into the scratch org. Then `force:source:push` works and my tests run successfully.

**The problem comes when I try to create a package version.** When I use `force:package:version:create` I get the `Variable does not exist: Type__c` error again. The field is defined in both production and the scratch org, so I don't understand "where" the package version is being created such that it doesn't see that field.

Accessing a custom field from an SFDX-based package seems like a pretty common use case, so I have a feeling I'm misunderstanding something basic. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong, and offer an approach that works? Thanks very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The field needs to exist in the package (or a parent package). This means you'd have a file in objects/Contact/fields/Type__c.field-meta.xml that represents the field in question. A package must be a complete replica of the data, including any dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! That's the approach I took in an earlier attempt.  I had converted the `Contact` metadata to source format, and included that as part of the package under `force-app/main/default/objects/`. That worked, but with a nasty side-effect: SF now says it will *delete the custom fields* if I uninstall the package. Worse, I'm unable to install a second package that refers to the custom field using the same technique, as I get an error that `Type__c` is already defined in another package. How can I work around that?

Comment: @JeffGarbers You use dependencies to manage this. The base package would have the common fields/objects/etc, and dependent packages would add additional metadata. In your example, Type__c would be in a common package A, and two dependent packages B and C with their respective code.

Comment: Okay, that's a strategy I was thinking about. I still have a Catch-22, though, I think. If I move all the custom fields and objects into package A, I can't install A because there's already an existing package B that "defined" some of those objects. And if I uninstall "B", SF says it'll delete the fields and associated data...!? Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Oh, and: I tried uninstalling my "B" package from a sandbox, just to see if it would actually delete the custom fields it carried. Instead I got an error saying that other parts of SF were using those fields, so I couldn't delete the package. I have a bad feeling I've gotten myself well stuck.

Comment: @JeffGarbers Yeah, once you've committed to a package, it's really hard to fix things. My only real advice would be to create a new package with a namespace, move the field over there, move all references to the new field, upload the new version, migrate your data, then uninstall the old version. Yes, this is a lot of work, but probably your only real solution at this point. To confirm, though, I'd suggest you contact support first.

Comment: I'm back up and running with a variation on your last idea. I created "hollowed out" versions of each of the packages that had "owned" the custom fields, eliminating the objects and all references to them. I installed those packages, and then created and installed a new package to own all the custom fields. I then reverted the code for all of the original packages to how they'd been before -- except for omitting the object definitions -- and installed those. No data was lost, nor was there any import or export necessary. Phew!

Comment: @JeffGarbers Nice. You might want to post your own answer with more details. I'd be interested in seeing the exact steps, and I suspect it will help other people.